# how to layout bootstrap form with multi column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

what I want is like this:

**5 element:**  label , textfield , read-only-label, auto-fill-textfield, icon-btn

and some spacer between them just as the img show.

[image: what I want]

but I found it's really hard to handle this.

could anyone show me an example jsfiddle, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for asking a question and found answer so quickly.

should I delete this question?

at last, I use this: http://jsfiddle.net/3QGpr/3/

```
  .container-fluid
      form.form-horizontal
        legend 请求参数
        .control-group
          label.control-label 回执编码：
          input.input-small(type='text')
          | &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;
          input.input-xlarge(type='text')
          | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          i.icon-trash

        .control-group
          label.control-label 回执编码：
          input.input-small(type='text')
          | &nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;
          input.input-xlarge(type='text')
          | &nbsp;&nbsp;
          i.icon-trash
```